# can't update or install any nuget packages in vs 2017

Tags: xamarin, nuget, visual-studio-2017, updates, nuget-package

I just installed vs 2017 and wanted to run my project but i'm facing so many warning and errors so I realized I should update my `xamarin.android nuget` packages but I keep getting this error message below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 27.0.2-preview1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.           0
```

Repairing vs didn't work; deleting `nuget.config` didn't work; I even changed the version in `.csproj` file, but when i load the project it goes back to v8.0.

Can anybody please help?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can't update or install any nuget packages in vs 2017

Just as Jon said, the latest nuget package `Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 27.0.2-preview1`, which requires **MonoAndroid81** at minimum to install.

However, only the **latest Preview (15.6 Preview 2)** version of Visual Studio includes Android 8.1 support. As this moment, current release version is `15.5.4`, preview release version is `15.6 Preview 2`. So if you want use that nuget package the latest version `27.0.2-preview1`, you need download the latest version of Visual Studio [15.6 Preview 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) and install Android SDK 8.1.

If switch to Visual Studio 15.6 Preview 2 is not your choice, you should not update that package to the latest version, just use the version **26.1.0.1**.

Hope this answer more clear.

Answer (score 2):

This requires `MonoAndroid81` at minimum to install. You can use the current `Preview` which includes Android 8.1 support:

https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-android-now-double-stuffed-with-oreo-8-1/

For future reference, the support library has a major version that maps with the Android version it supports. In this case **Support v27 = Android 8.1 (API 27)**

Comment: so i am a newbie, could you please explain a little more about what i should do now? and i don't see any android 8.1 in target version dropdown box, i added a photo to my question

Comment: That is the `targetSdkVersion` whiich is not the correct area. It would be `<TargetFramework>`. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

Answer (score 0):

When errors appear, clean your solution and rebuild it.

Also do something very basic, that what you are going to download is  "accessible " in .Droid and that is not only in the Portable.

If you do not serve, and do not find a solution, you must start a new project, it would be advisable to install the latest SDK, etc.